# Lag on Windows 7 whenever typing

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cpu-usage

Whenever I type in windows 7 my cpu usage increases dramatically and my words "cant keep up". I have tried using another keyboard and using ccleaner however none of this works. I don't think this is to do with my hardware as I have i5 cpu, a gtx 760 gpu and 8gb of ram. Below is some gifs of what it looks like:

[In a web browser](http://gyazo.com/428f2fe4d6139aea6253185d89feb4fb) (Thats just me spamming the keyboard)

[With performance stats](http://gyazo.com/a6a8ad19baac1f04e4243672d58caf56) (That's my cpu usage doubling when I type)

Comment: follow this http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3 and share the trace file

Answer (score 1):

Try scanning your system with an antivirus. It might be a keylogger.

Comment: I suggest trying malwarebytes.

Answer (score 0):

Go in to your bios and check your cpu temp, with and withought typing. standard temp should be around 50 degrease Celsius. if its normal, it might be a key logger or virus of sorts. if its higher, i'd recommend you check your cpu fan is contacting the cpu through the thermal paste. being intel this can sometimes be a problem and can creat high lag/delay. if your not sure exactly how to do this, there should be 4 pins in each corner of the fan, make sure there presses firmly.

Hope this helps